# Detectar mudança de fase, navigator.online

Tags: javascript

Uso isto `navigator.onLine` para checar se o usuário está conectado, entretanto eu preciso verificar constantemente e uso `setInterval` para isso, existe uma forma mais elegante que deixe essa gambiarra para trás tipo um `on('navigator.online')` ?

Para verificar faço um mero

```
if(navigator.onLine) == conectado 
else == nao conectado
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Segundo a MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) existem ambos os eventos `online` e `offline`, assim podes detetar mudanças instantaneamente e saber o estado sempre que precisares sem precisar de `setTinterval`.

```
var online = navigator.onLine;
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) { online = false; });
window.addEventListener("online", function(e) { online = true; });
alert(online);
```

## Edit:

Precisei desta funcionalidade num projeto e percebí que a minha primeira resposta tem falhas. O problema dela é que diferentes browsers têm diferentes entendimentos do que é `online` e `offline`.

Encontrei outra solução que é de confiar. Precisa de usar o teu servidor e faz-se de 2 maneiras diferentes dependendo de teres [CORS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129) ativado ou não.

### Com CORS ativo:

```
function testaLigacao(callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://teusite.com"; // <--- o teu url aqui
    var novoNumero = new Date().getTime();

    xhr.open('HEAD', url + "?rand=" + novoNumero, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
        if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 304) return callback(xhr.responseText, true);
        return callback(xhr.responseText, false);
    }
    try {
        xhr.send();
    } catch (e) {
        return callback(e, false);
    }
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h36no4vh/ *

<sup>* - este jsFiddle é emxemplo de como usar, não funciona porque está a usar um url fictício. Tens de usar o teu url</sup>

### Com CORS bloqueado:

Neste caso vais ter de usar JSONP, e ter uma página que faça echo conforme o JSONP precisa. O JavaScript é:

```
function testaLigacao(callback) {
    var response;
    var callbackName = 'temp_callback_' + new Date().getTime() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    window[callbackName] = function (res) {
        delete window[callbackName];
        document.body.removeChild(script);
        response = res;
    };

    var src = 'http://teusite.com/ping.php?callback=' + callbackName;
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = function () {
        callback(true);
    }
    script.onerror = function () {
        callback(false);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

#### jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aunrh78o/ *

<sup>* - este jsFiddle é emxemplo de como usar, não funciona porque está a usar um url fictício. Tens de usar o teu url</sup>

Mais sobre JSONP [aqui (link)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70267/129).
Mais sobre CORS [aqui (link)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/145493/129)