# Verificar status da conexão

Tags: javascript, jquery

Queria evitar que a conexão *offline* do usuário fizesse requisições desnecessárias para não ter que esperar retorno *timeout* ou qualquer outro erro...

Existe alguma função em javascript capaz de verificar o status da conexão da internet do usuário?

Comment: Já viste http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/66677/129 ?

Comment: @Sergio, não tinha visto, é a mesma pergunta rs. Devo deletar ou marcar como duplicata?

Comment: Por mim podes deixar ficar, mas faz como achares melhor. Se não encontraste é porque a outra usou outras palavras, e por isso pode ser bom ter a tua pergunta aqui.

Comment: Por mim pode marcar como duplicata sem problema. Já que `navigator.onLine` não é confiável, mais fácil fica eu trabalhar o status das requisições mesmo. TKS